# "Not In" If statement not operating correctly

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
if ('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR') not in words[i]:
   list_stat.append(words[i])
       i=i+1
       print words[i]
   else:
       i=i+1
```

I am trying to create an `or` statement in Python to parse a list. The number of keywords is a lot longer than the three you see in the if statement, so nested if statements would get really redundant really quick. I'm kind of new to Python but a `not in` statement seemed to be most efficient for grouping all of my keywords together. Problem is, I keep getting errors for trying to compare a tuple to the array. I've tried it this way as well:

```
if words[i] not in ('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR'):
   list_stat.append(words[i])
        i=i+1
        print words[i]
   else:
        i=i+1
```

Neither work correctly. I should also mention that the second way runs without error, but doesn't remove the words from my list. The three words appear individually multiple times throughout my list, even though the whole point of the not in statement was to get rid of them. I am trying to get rid of all individual instances of these words. I have tried {} instead of () as well but neither will get rid of the individual words in my list. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the  words[i] value? We aren't magics.

Comment: The second one looks more likely to work, but your indentation is unusual in either case.

Comment: The second one looks like it should work, except for the bad indentation. What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: `if ('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR') not in words[i]` -> "if the tuple `('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR')` is not in whatever data structure `words[i]` is"

Comment: Also, I guess you want `if not any(j in words[i] for j in ('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR'))`

Comment: I apologize for the indentation. I just deleted a little space while copy and pasting (this is my first time actually posting on here). The indentation is correct in the actual file.

Comment: You have a list of keywords, and a list of words, and you want to make a new list of everything that is in words but not in keywords?  What about duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are probably because of indentation errors. Besides this, you could use a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop which will simplify things (it will do the `i=i+1` for you):

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] not in ['SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR']:
        list_stat.append(words[i])
        print words[i]
```

> doesn't remove the words from my list

Either way you're populating a new list (`list_stat`), not deleting from `words`.

Comment: The integer doesn't seem to serve a purpose here.  You could have used "for word in words"

Comment: You're right, although I'm not sure this is the whole code. Also, [ginger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4339728/ginger) seems to be aware of the `in` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_stat.append([x for x in words if x not in ('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR')])
```

"Make a list from every word in `words`, provided it's not in `('SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR')`. Append this new list to `list_stat`"

Answer (score -1):

You don't explain what exactly your'e trying to do, but it appears like you're implementing set operations - which have native implementation in python

see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

specifically:

```
if set(['SCT', 'OVC', 'CLR']) & words[i] # intersection is not empty - one of the words is in words[i]
...
```